# Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 3.15.138.43:8080 do I need IAM AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, flask, amazon-ec2, deployment

I am new to docker,linux and AWS I followed this great tutorial(part 1 and 2 below) to dockerize a flask app and deploying to EC2.

https://dev.to/aminu_israel/build-and-deploy-your-machine-learning-application-with-docker-5322
https://dev.to/aminu_israel/dockerize-and-deploy-your-machine-learning-application-on-aws-5160

Yet still I get this Error: connect ECONNREFUSED everytime I try to do the POST request in Postman or the Curl Request but the app works perfectly in localhost.
Here are my inbound rules security settings in EC2 since I saw this was a typical point of confusion(i tried all combinations)

[Inbound rules](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y2qmO.png)

[Outbound rules](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TL5Y8.png)

[NACL INBOUND](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WNdTZ.png)

[NACL OUTBOUND](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wrbJq.png)

All my ports seem to align properly

[Container running in EC2 Instance](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kcNNc.png)

These and other tutorials mention nothing about IAM AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID or AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY but they still got apps to deploy.Do I need this somewhere in my dockerfile or in the terminal?If so can you give a an example?Or these settings aren't necessary to deploy?I can't sleep :(

Comment: Do you get 'GET' response on EC2?

Comment: its just set for post @app.route("/predict", methods=['POST'])

Comment: should I build an image with GET?The POST request did work for localhost

Comment: I could see `app.py` don't have any `POST`. I see `@flask_app.route('/predict',methods=['GET'])`. Am I missing anything?

Comment: Could you please share your `app.py` code and `POST` response here? Will be helpful to understand the problem.

Comment: shared @ChandanKumar

Comment: What is your outbound rules?

Comment: Please check NACL rules too.

Comment: Please note:
Your security group should allow outbound traffic on port 80.
Your network ACL should allow outbound traffic on port 80.

Comment: didnt know about ACL rules looking for that now

Comment: NACL say all traffic for both inbound and outbound

Comment: And how about attached Security Group Outbound rules?

Comment: Security group outbound-All Traffic                                                                               
let me add some more pictures of these above

Comment: @ChandanKumar added all pictures

Comment: Strange! Could you share the output of `sudo netstat -anlp |grep 8080`. Let's see what's listening on port 8080.

Comment: This application should be listening to applications coming from outside connections. i.e. `0.0.0.0:8080` If you get `127.0.0.1:8080` in that above command's output then it has some problem. To listen outside traffic it should return you `0.0.0.0:8080`

Comment: just to clarify? I am doing this on the EC2 instance right?

Comment: Right, need to do on EC2

Comment: @ChandanKumar it returns nothing on the EC2 instance.Can we talk offline? and I send you more pictures.

Comment: Sure, we can discuss offline. Over email?

Comment: yes @ChandanKumar raedjamw@gmail.com